# Embedded TableView not displaying TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView within a ViewController and connected it the following way to the view controller:

```
@interface ChooseViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

I am selecting the cell for the table view the following way:

```
SongTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SongTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

I dragged `SongTableViewCell` into the `tableView` in storyboard by the way. I then added an `imageView` to `SongTableViewCell` and set the image.

The imageView in `SongTableViewCell` is not displaying in the app though. Do you see anything I did wrong?

Is it possibly because I setup tableView as an IBOutlet? `SongTableViewCell *cell` is called in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

*Note: I also control dragged `tableView` to the view controller it is in and selected `delegate`.

Comment: have you checked that SongTableViewCell have defined it's Identifier as "SongTableViewCell" in Inspector?

Comment: Do you have given "SongTableViewCell" as identifier in storyboard?

Comment: Yes, SongTableViewCell has the identifier "SongTableViewCell" in storyboard inspector.

Comment: You gave the tableview a delegate but did you give it a datasource? Also, did you implement both tableview delegates methods?

Comment: Is there any reason you have neglected to make your controller conform to `<UITableViewDataSource>`

Comment: I'm using the table view as thing where when you tap on a cell, it adds a string to an array, so I don't need it to be a datasource. Also, what tableview delegates methods?

Comment: Yes but you still need to feed data to the table view? And construct it's cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect your tableview as datasource to display cells in tableview and you should connect your tableview for UITableViewDelegate to detect events like didSelect on particular row at indexpath. So make sure have connected for datasource.

Answer (score 0):

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SongTableViewCell"
```

Im guessing that you did not actually give the cell a cell identifier.  Open the storyboard and select the cell in the tableview.  Open the property inspector for the cell and set the cell identifier to what you want.